# Do malloc and new return an int-aligned address?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658615/bitwise-operations-is-this-code-safe-and-portable) I asked related to bitwise operations I was told that a code that accesses to a `char` array with an `int` pointer (to operate on bigger chunks of bytes at a time) may be problematic if the `char` array is not aligned with a `int` address.

Then, thinking in C, I wondered what goes on when `malloc` allocates memory for an unknown type. For example, if I do `void *p = malloc(sizeof(int));`, do I get a valid char/int/long-aligned memory address?

According to [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506518/is-there-any-guarantee-of-alignment-of-address-return-by-cs-new-operation) here in SO that cite the standard, "the pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer of any complete object type".

Thus, I understand that I can go from `char*` to `int*` with no problems in this case:

```c
char *p = malloc(16);
int *n = (int*)p; // use n a base of an array of 16 / sizeof(int) ints
```

Is it correct?

Moving to C++, it seems that [the same rule appears in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660076/returning-aligned-memory-with-new). Then, can I assume that there are not alignment risks if I do this?

```c
char *p = new char[16];
int *n = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
```

Comment: @JensGustedt I removed the comment, must have mis-read the code. I'm sure I thought there was a cast in the C code. Weird.

Comment: Yes, there was a cast, but I removed it after seeing your comment, @unwind. Sorry for not saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, both `malloc` in C and C++ and `new char[N]` in C++ return a pointer that is maximally aligned. The alignment is that of the type `max_align_t` from  or .

gcc-4.8 has a bug in this regard, fixed in gcc-4.9. Just include  and use `::maxalign_t` without the `std::` prefix.

Support for *over*-aligned types, i.e. those whose alignment is greater than the above maximum, is implementation-defined. E.g. Posix offers `posix_memalign` to allocate memory with much greater alignments (e.g. page-aligned).

Comment: @user1095108: It's a whole can of worms how `<header.h>`  and `<cheader>` interact with `std` and global namespaces - I think the net effect is that Nobody Knows For Sure and that you always have to have both... :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB - lest people get the wrong impression, `<cheader>` will **always** put names into `std` and `<header.h`>` will **always** put names into the global namespace. It is indeed true that Nobody Knows For Sure what gets into the **other** namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* p = new char[16];
int* n = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
```

This is fine, but even better is:

```
char* p = new char[16];
int* n = static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(p));
```

Alternatively, you can use C++'s `operator new`, like this:

```
void* p = operator new(16);
int* n = static_cast<int*>(p);
```

Making for one less `static_cast`.

Comment: Could you tell me the benefits from using two static casts?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger `reinterpret_cast` will work on almost anything. But `static_cast` won't, it is safer and more portable to use. You don't need to use it in this case.

Comment: Note that C++11 explicitly makes `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)` equivalent to `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(p))` in [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7.

Comment: @avakar but the argument of a `reinterpret_cast` could be anything, even a function pointer would be cast to `int*`, which is not possible with a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns an address which is aligned correctly for *any* base type in C. That means it can be cast safely to pointers for all those types (`int`, long, `double` and so on).

Comment: It may be worth noting that the pointers are only required to have whatever alignment would be necessary to make them usable; if an architecture would have no problem reading a `long long` from an odd byte address, an implementation could legitimately return an odd byte address from `malloc`.